# Fragment to fragment is overlapping

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, fragment, overlapping

I want to open a fragment from my `recyclerview` adapter class. I am using holder class in `bindviewholder`, where I code to open my fragment but it overlaps on the current fragment.

```
holder.buys.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getcall();
            }
        });
```

and

```
public void getcall() {
        FragmentManager fm = context.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        Buy b = new Buy();
        ft.replace(R.id.p_buy, b);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

Comment: holder.buys.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {

                getcall();
            }
        });


    }

    public void getcall()
    {

        FragmentManager fm=context.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
        Buy b=new Buy();
        ft.replace(R.id.p_buy,b);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();

    }

Comment: Please add the neccessary code to your question, don't use images or the comment section for this

Comment: Just add 'android:clickable="true"` in parent layout of your fragment's layout xml file.

Comment: Your link is dead so I removed it